# Count number of order products

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get the count of order products associated with an order.
Here is my code:

```
//count the number of lines in the actual order
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("salesorderdetail");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("salesorderid");
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition("salesorderid", ConditionOperator.Equal, order.Id);
EntityCollection response = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

For some reasons when I use response.TotalRecordCount I have -1 as the count, even if there are some records.
I guess the -1 is related to a problem, is there anything wrong in the expression?

Comment: `response.Entities.Count()`

Answer (score 1):

You could/should use FetchXML to do the query as you are reducing the amount of data being sent from CRM to your local machine. Here is a sample fetch statement that will do what you want

```
<fetch mapping="logical" aggregate='true'>
<entity name="salesorderdetail">
    <attribute name="salesorderid" aggregate="countcolumn" alias='test'/>
    <filter>
        <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq" value="e076c06a-6609-4aca-b0f4-a5075997378b" />
    </filter>
</entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an extension method for IOrganizationService.

Call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("# of Account records: {0}", 
    service.Count(Account.EntityLogicalName));
```

The extension method:

```
public static int Count(this IOrganizationService service, string entityLogicalName)
{
    string fetch = "<fetch distinct='true' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'>";
    fetch += string.Format("<entity name='{0}'>", entityLogicalName);
    fetch += "<attribute name='createdon' alias='count' aggregate='count' />";
    fetch += "</entity></fetch>";
    int count = -1;
    try
    {
        var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
        count = (Int32)((AliasedValue)result.Entities.First()["count"]).Value;
    }
    catch { }
    return count;
}
```

If you edit the FetchXML to Kevin's it should work well.
FetchXML can only count to 50000.